# Calcular diferença de datas e comparar com campo integer em expressão lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expressões-lambda

Tenho um campo data(DateTime) e também um campo do tipo integer. Preciso fazer a diferença entre esse campo data e data de hoje(DateTime.Now) e comparar se é maior ou menor que o meu campo integer. Fiz e dá esse erro.

```
Oprerator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.TimeSpan' and 'int'
```

Essa é minha expressão:

```
var atendimento = db.T_CRM_StatusPDV
                              .Where(dt => (dt.DT_TransacaoV - DateTime.Now) > dt.DE_FrequenciaTrans)
```

Comment: Esse seu valor inteiro representa o que? horas, minutos, segundos, milisegundos?

Comment: são dias, inteiro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta pegar a parte de dias do `TimeSpan`:

```
var atendimento = db.T_CRM_StatusPDV
                  .Where(dt => ((TimeSpan)(dt.DT_TransacaoV - DateTime.Now)).Days > dt.DE_FrequenciaTrans)
```

Referência: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days.aspx

Se o número de dias permitir parte fracionária, tente `TotalDays`:

```
var atendimento = db.T_CRM_StatusPDV
                  .Where(dt => ((TimeSpan)(dt.DT_TransacaoV - DateTime.Now)).TotalDays > dt.DE_FrequenciaTrans)
```

Comment: @pnet Acho que não. [Aqui neste link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timespan.days(v=vs.110).aspx) diz que `TimeSpan` pertence a `System`. Deveria ter encontrado.

Comment: @pnet Editei a resposta. Veja se agora funciona pra você.

Comment: @pnet Não sei se tem a ver com o `TimeSpan` ser nulo, mas fiz mais uma edição em que se faz um cast pro tipo certo.

Comment: @pnet Qualquer coisa, acho legal você obter o valor não-nulo antes de aplicar o `Where`.